# Getting actual entity version after entity save method call (entity merge) in transaction

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, merge, spring-data-jpa

I have entity with version field:

```
    @Entity
    public class Cat {
       @Id
       private Long id;

       *************** other fields

        @Version
        private Integer version;
    }
```

I want to send the information about entity after save repo method call to broker (this is like checkpoint-snapshot for sending information, several checkpoints during one transaction). Sending to broker means persisting info about entity to string and then to broker message entity in DB. I need to get actual version of entity for this snapshot message but I can't get actual (version from DB + 1 cause entity edit). As example:

```
@Transactional
public class test(long catId) {
   Cat cat = catRepo.findById(catId);
   cat.setColor(red);
   cat = catRepo.save(cat); // here cat will be with version = 0
   broker.send(cat); // persisting message to DB 4 future sending to broker
   
   cat.setColor(green);
   cat = catRepo.save(cat);
   broker.send(cat); // persisting message to DB 4 future sending to broker
}
```

But after saving the entity I have version = 0 in "merged" object. Or old version in argument of save-method. How can I get actual version that is increased in case of entity dirty-change? I know that the version is changed during flush but I can't do flush with save method. May be some other variant to get actual version

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `jakarta.transaction.Synchronization` for this purpose to get a callback after a transaction commits. Another alternative is to use a Hibernate `Interceptor` to get a callback when flushing occurs. See the [Hibernate documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#events) for details. Here is also a tutorial about [Hibernate interceptors](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-interceptor)